# phpMyAdmin creating

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I attached a screen shot from my phpMyadmin and the code for my table.
I can't lunch the code below without getting : `#1146 - Table 'patlaza2_Premiere.customer' doesn't exist`

What can be the problem and any idea how to fix it please?

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME, BALANCE, CREDIT_LIMIT
FROM customer
```

https://gyazo.com/edd75cc3b02659525fb0bbe27fdd4f1c

```
CREATE TABLE Rep
(RepNum CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName CHAR(15),
FirstName CHAR(15),
Street CHAR(15),
City CHAR(15),
State CHAR(2),
Zip CHAR(5),
Commission DECIMAL(7,2),
Rate DECIMAL(3,2) );

CREATE TABLE Customer
(CustomerNum CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
Street CHAR(15),
City CHAR(15),
State CHAR(2),
Zip CHAR(5),
Balance DECIMAL(8,2),
CreditLimit DECIMAL(8,2),
RepNum CHAR(2) );

CREATE TABLE Orders
(OrderNum CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
OrderDate DATE,
CustomerNum CHAR(3) );

CREATE TABLE Part
(PartNum CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
Description CHAR(15),
OnHand DECIMAL(4,0),
Class CHAR(2),
Warehouse CHAR(1),
Price DECIMAL(6,2) );

CREATE TABLE OrderLine
(OrderNum CHAR(5),
PartNum CHAR(4),
NumOrdered DECIMAL(3,0),
QuotedPrice DECIMAL(6,2),
PRIMARY KEY (OrderNum, PartNum) );

INSERT INTO Rep
VALUES
('20','Kaiser','Valerie','624 Randall','Grove','FL','33321',20542.50,0.05);
INSERT INTO Rep
VALUES
('35','Hull','Richard','532 Jackson','Sheldon','FL','33553',39216.00,0.07);
INSERT INTO Rep
VALUES
('65','Perez','Juan','1626 Taylor','Fillmore','FL','33336',23487.00,0.05);
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('148','Al''s Appliance and Sport','2837 Greenway','Fillmore','FL','33336',6550.00,7500.00,'20');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('282','Brookings Direct','3827 Devon','Grove','FL','33321',431.50,10000.00,'35');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('356','Ferguson''s','382 Wildwood','Northfield','FL','33146',5785.00,7500.00,'65');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('408','The Everything Shop','1828 Raven','Crystal','FL','33503',5285.25,5000.00,'35');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('462','Bargains Galore','3829 Central','Grove','FL','33321',3412.00,10000.00,'65');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('524','Kline''s','838 Ridgeland','Fillmore','FL','33336',12762.00,15000.00,'20');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('608','Johnson''s Department Store','372 Oxford','Sheldon','FL','33553',2106.00,10000.00,'65');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('687','Lee''s Sport and Appliance','282 Evergreen','Altonville','FL','32543',2851.00,5000.00,'35');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('725','Deerfield''s Four Seasons','282 Columbia','Sheldon','FL','33553',248.00,7500.00,'35');
INSERT INTO Customer
VALUES
('842','All Season','28 Lakeview','Grove','FL','33321',8221.00,7500.00,'20');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21608','2013-10-20','148');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21610','2013-10-20','356');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21613','2013-10-21','408');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21614','2013-10-21','282');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21617','2013-10-23','608');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21619','2013-10-23','148');
INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
('21623','2013-10-23','608');
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('AT94','Iron',50,'HW','3',24.95);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('BV06','Home Gym',45,'SG','2',794.95);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('CD52','Microwave Oven',32,'AP','1',165.00);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('DL71','Cordless Drill',21,'HW','3',129.95);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('DR93','Gas Range',8,'AP','2',495.00);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('DW11','Washer',12,'AP','3',399.99);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('FD21','Stand Mixer',22,'HW','3',159.95);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('KL62','Dryer',12,'AP','1',349.95);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('KT03','Dishwasher',8,'AP','3',595.00);
INSERT INTO Part
VALUES
('KV29','Treadmill',9,'SG','2',1390.00);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21608','AT94',11,21.95);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21610','DR93',1,495.00);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21610','DW11',1,399.99);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21613','KL62',4,329.95);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21614','KT03',2,595.00);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21617','BV06',2,794.95);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21617','CD52',4,150.00);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21619','DR93',1,495.00);
INSERT INTO OrderLine
VALUES
('21623','KV29',2,1290.00);
```

Comment: that code could use some formatting

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your post: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And please include images directly instead of attaching an external link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The only table that exists in the `patlaza2_Premiere` database is `TABLE 1`. Before running your create table statements, run this: `use patlaza2_Premiere;` to explicitly tell mysql which database you want to use.

Alternatively, if you click on the `patlaza2_Premiere` database link in the sidebar menu of phpmyadmin, that will automatically issue the `use patlaza2_Premiere` command and you can then run your create table statements.